# MariaDB connector (remote)

Tags: raspberry-pi, mariadb, matlab, mysql-connection, odbc

I'm new to databases and have some very basic how-to/where-to questions:

1. I have successfully setup a MariaDB + phpmyadmin on my raspberrypi zero (running the latest diet-pi), including a database with a couple of columns, which works like a charm.
2. Now, under Windows, I would like to import the data into Matlab, using `adodb_connect()`, created by the community ([link](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29615-adodb_tools)), to analyze some data that I stored in the database. From the docs of that file:

> Package adodb_toolbox allows communication with different types of databases through Microsoft's ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) OLEDB component. The package was designed to work on Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, Microsoft Access, MySQL and other databases.

However I can't find good and straightforward guide on how to install ODBC on my raspberry pi (as far as I understand MariaDB should, for all intents and purposes, classify as a 'MYSQL database'), this usually means I'm not following the most common implementations anymore, which is why I'm asking for some general questions (after reading/googling):

- Would you (e.g. a poweruser or expert) have advice on a more straight forward option to import the data to Matlab (or even Java, or even Windows) from my SQL database rather than this OLEDB interface? (the goal here is to make the database as accessible as possible)
- Is there a good guide or resource I should follow to install this (database connector or whatever would be more advisable) on my raspberry pi?

thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this project, it might help: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/odbcinst/odbcinst.1.en.html (source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/creating-a-data-source-with-mariadb-connectorodbc/)

Comment: @1nternetz ok, this is where google got me, and it seemed incredibly complicated. I guess many things do until you understand them, i.e. that will be my next step

Comment: if you post an answer I can accept the solution =)

Comment: Have you been able to make it work? I don't feel my solution was the answer. However, if I can help you find a solution, I'll gladly post an answer. :)

Comment: Oh- since your answer converged with practically the only guide I found (and no other answers were posted), I presumed it just means that 'this is the way to go' and if I want to implement it properly, I should just follow that guide. Seemed fair enough as advice